# Get cumulative counts for unique item in R

Tags: r

I have below table:

| date | countrycode |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-12 | GBR |
| 2020-03-16 | CHE |
| 2020-03-16 | CHE |
| 2020-03-18 | SGP |

How can I get the cumulative counts for each country code and get the output in the third column like below table in R?

| date | countrycode | counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-12 | GBR | GBR,1 |
| 2020-03-16 | CHE | GBR,1;CHE,1 |
| 2020-03-16 | CHE | CHE,2;GBR,1 |
| 2020-03-18 | SGP | CHE,2;GBR,1;SGP,1 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option using `Reduce` + `stack` + `table`

```
transform(
  df,
  counts = sapply(
    Reduce(c,countrycode,accumulate = TRUE),
    function(x) paste0(
      do.call(
        paste,
        c(rev(stack(table(x))),sep = ",")),
      collapse = ";"))
)
```

gives

```
        date countrycode            counts
1 2020-03-12         GBR             GBR,1
2 2020-03-16         CHE       CHE,1;GBR,1
3 2020-03-16         CHE       CHE,2;GBR,1
4 2020-03-18         SGP CHE,2;GBR,1;SGP,1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(date = c("2020-03-12", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-16", 
"2020-03-18"), countrycode = c("GBR", "CHE", "CHE", "SGP")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Similar option in tidyverse `df1 %>% mutate(tmp = accumulate(countrycode, c), tmp1 = accumulate(rowid(countrycode), c), count = map2_chr(tmp, tmp1, ~ {i1 <- order(.x); .x <- .x[i1]; .y <- .y[i1]  ;i2 <- !duplicated(.x, fromLast = TRUE); str_c(.x[i2], .y[i2], sep=",", collapse=";")} ), tmp = NULL, tmp1 = NULL)`

Comment: @akrun, it will be helpful if you could explain the syntax in simple terms as it looks very complex.  Better write that as an answer

Comment: @AnilGoyal that is almost similar to ThomasIsCoding as I got the idea from his post